# How do you Insert line break in SC.say smartgwt?

Tags: smartgwt

I have a message I want to show but i don't know how to insert a line break.

**Example:** 
`SC.say("Hello world. \n Bye.")` does not show a message with **Bye** on a new line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Standard HTML - use a `<br>` tag.